# .post form data to php

Tags: php, json, .post

Im sending the form data as below:

```
j.post('data_handler.php', {
        flag: 'signUp',
        username: username,
        password: password_register,
        birthDate: birthDate,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email
    },
```

and the data_handler.php get the info:

```
case 'signUp': //flag

        // Get the user signup information
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
        $birthDate = $_POST['birthDate'].'T23:30:58.000Z';
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
```

and passes to a function :

```
ValidateReg($user, $password, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $birthDate);
```

... and for some reason the data is not passed, all empty/blank; what i am doing wrong, suggestions/help please, thanks!

Comment: check for php errors and your console. Plus, if you don't have a `break` for your `case`, that will fail. Refs: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: yes i have it, theres more code after that and then 
break;

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved! There was a php version issue (localhost) and the .post